# Adjusting position of text labels in coord_polar() histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm stuck on an small labeling issue with a series of polar histograms made in ggplot2 (circumplexes? how are these things called?).

Here is a simplified example of how the data and the graph look:

```
df <- data.frame(Attribute1=10, Attribute2=1, Attribute3=2,  Attribute4=6,  Attribute5=7)
g <- ggplot(melt.data.frame(df), aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=variable, label=value))
g <- g + geom_bar() + geom_text() + coord_polar()
g
```

Which gives the following graph:
[image: polar histogram example]

I would like to move the text labels outwards (away from the center).

Normally, I would adjust the position with `hjust` or `vjust` inside `geom_text()`, but it seems that, with `coord_polar()`, the result is to move all the labels up/downwards or left/rightwards, but not in/outwards.

This may sound trivial - and probably is - but I haven't found any applicable example or workaround yet, so I apologize if this question looks silly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're referring to the numeric values as labels, and that you want them moved a little outside the pie wedges (as opposed to the "Attribute 1" text).

You can just move some of the aesthetic mapping to the `geom_text` call and add a small value to the y values:

```
g <- ggplot(melt.data.frame(df), aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=variable))
g <- g + geom_bar() + geom_text(aes(y = value + 0.5,label = value)) + coord_polar()
g
```

[image]